# Hibernate override "lazy=false"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a new module in an existing project. The project already has a user table, a pojo and a corresponding mapping file. The problem is that they are fetching all the properties eagerly by mentioning **lazy="false"**. But, in my module, I am doing lot of read & write in a single request, so I don't want to fetch eagerly. What I want to know is that, is it possible to create an another mapping file for the same table & same pojo to load all the properties lazily? I have tried by assigning different **entity-name** for the mapping files, but while deploying, I am getting the error **"Repeated column in mapping for entity"**.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815209/hibernate-mapping-setting-lazy-false) answer, but it says **"do not map child"**, then how will I get the proxies?

Answer (score 3):

That's one major drawback for using EAGER fetching as the default strategy. Usually you'd have a LAZY children collection that you can [eagerly fetch on a HQL query basis](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-stratgey/).

What's worth mentioning is that [HQL/Criteria queries overrule the default fetch strategy](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/) (the one given by your entity mappings) so that you can explicitly specify what to fetch.

For Criteria queries, you might give a try to [Criteria.setFetchMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFetchMode%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.FetchMode%29) FetchMode.LAZY, although it's deprecated.

Another way to overrule the EAGER fetching is to use a [`javax.persistence.fetchgraph`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm). This way, you can specify what you want to fetch and all the EAGER fetching properties that were not included in the Entity Graph are going to be fetched lazily.

Answer (score 2):

I think, your question is to not to load associated entity , egarly ? 
for this when :
FetchType.LAZY = Doesn’t load the relationships unless explicitly called via getter.
FetchType.EAGER = Loads ALL relationships default

In your case , if my understanding is correct then use
lazy="false"
fetch="select"   so it will select on demand via getter. 
check this url , it will give more clear idea :
[**Hibernate XML Mapping: Lazy False or Fetch Select?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374528/hibernate-xml-mapping-lazy-false-or-fetch-select)
[**A Short Primer On Fetching Strategies**](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 1):

The point [Hibernate mapping setting lazy = 'false'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815209/hibernate-mapping-setting-lazy-false) is making, is that you can map the same table twice if you use two different java classes. In your case, if you know for a fact that setting lazy="true" will suffice:

1. create empty subclass of your pojo
2. map your subclass the way you want to the same user table (for examply copy-pasting the existing mapping and changing lazy property value)
3. in the module you create only use the subclass

Answer (score 0):

Like Vlad Mihalcea said, use Criteria API it will work. I've tried it :)

```
Criteria c =  session.createCriteria(YourHibernateClass.class);
c.setFetchMode(urLazyPropName,FetchMode.LAZY);
```

Atleast this you can do with out changing existing hbm files

Answer (score 0):

Some **other approaches** mentioned we used **based on JPA inheritance (`@MappedSuperclass`) and/or database views** and examplified with the following pseudo code (it works both ways for *EAGER->LAZY* or *LAZY->EAGER* scenarios):

```
@Table( name = "table_x" )
@Entity
class DaoX { @...( fetch = FetchType.EAGER ) refY ;  /* ... other stuff ... */ }
```

- our `DaoX` used e.g. in other code like this:

  ```
  DaoX x ;

  @Entity
  class DaoZ {  DaoX x ; }
  ```

## via inheritance

so if we would like to have it lazily loaded we could pimp the inheritance hierarchy up like this with only minimal additional code:

```
@Table( name = "table_x" )
@MappedSuperclass
class abstract BaseDaoX { /* ... other stuff ... */ }

@Entity
class DaoX extends BaseDaoX { @...( fetch = FetchType.EAGER ) refY ; }

@Entity
class DaoXLazy extends BaseDaoX { @...( fetch = FetchType.LAZY ) refY ; }
```

- our `DaoX` usages should be substituted by `BaseDaoX` where possible (no direct JPA mapping)

  ```
  BaseDaoX x ;

  @Entity
  class DaoZ {  DaoX x ; }

  @Entity
  class DaoZLazy {  DaoXLazy x ; }
  ```

so you can use `DaoXLazy` or `DaoZLazy` for your desired scenarios.

## via views (in *LAZY->EAGER* scenarios)

(if you can change your current `EAGER` to `LAZY` which is generally more appropriate)
you could just map your (maybe deeply nested) lazy stuff with minimal load e.g. like this ( we like to load `prop_f1` and `prop_b1` here )

```sql
-- db view:
create or replace view view_x_eager as
select 
  tx.*,
  f.prop_f1,
  b.prop_b1
from table_x                 tx
  -- assuming tx:f ~ 1:1 and f:b ~ 1:1 for simplicity here:
  left outer join table_foo  f  on ( f.id = tx.foo_id )
  left outer join table_bar  b  on ( b.id = f.bar_id  )
```

---

```
@Table( name = "view_x_eager" )
class DaoXEager extends BaseDaoX { 
  @...( fetch = FetchType.EAGER ) refY ; 

  String prop_f1 ;
  String prop_b1 ;
}
```

Comment: Hi I'm using your MappedSuperClass inheritance strategy. However, I'm getting `Unknown column 'structures0_.project_lazy_id' in 'field list'`` where hibernate is changing the foreign key. I can't figure out how to keep that at default. Tried @JoinColumn, etc. See my code here: https://gist.github.com/nitrag/7d685355765aa88853862f560d21f0d8

Comment: Hi @Ryan, please aks in some hibernate forum or a new question on stackoverflow because I can't help you with this now. You could point others to your question with a comment here.