# Hibernate ManyToOne relation with multiple JoinColumn is not lazy fetched

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a following example  I want to create a lazy @ManyToOne relation between Car and CarAchievement tables using multiple join columns (example of class below)

[image: CarAchievement table]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "SEQ_CAR", strategy = "sequence",
        parameters = {
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                        name = "sequence",
                        value = "SEQ_CAR"
                        )
                }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_CAR")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "region", referencedColumnName = "region", updatable = false, insertable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "model", referencedColumnName = "model", updatable = false, insertable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "year", referencedColumnName = "type", updatable = false, insertable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "type", referencedColumnName = "year", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
    @JsonIgnore
    private CarAchievement carAchievement;
}
```

This relation works fine but it seems not to be a LazyFetch, every query for a CAR seems to be fetching CarAchievement automatically even when its not specified to fetch this relation

Hibernate version: 4.3.10.Final

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916563/hibernate-lazy-loading-not-work-with-many-to-one-mapping). This might be of some help.

Comment: Didn't help, but thanks! It's not a JSON serializer or watcher... FetchMode.SELECT didn't help either. This seems to happen inside Hibernate I've been debugging it inside and it populates this collection eagerly... when it shouldn't

Comment: Note that while `FetchMode.EAGER` is a *contract*, `FetchType.LAZY` is a *hint* which does not need to be respected by Hibernate at all.

Comment: NotFoundAction.IGNORE could be a problem.

Comment: @JimmyT. even without it, it doesn't work. The funny part is that there are some relations ManyToOne with LazyFetch and they seem to work.. the only difference is that this relation uses multiple JoinColumn, can this be the problem? Are there some patterns on how to replace a multiple column join with a single join? Except creating a View in database (that's my only idea at the moment)

Comment: Is region,model,year and type the primary key of `CarAchievement`?

Comment: @JimmyT. no, the primary key is ID the rest are just foreign keys

Comment: Ok, I've overlooked that. But that is exactly the problem. Hibernate can't create a proxy object if you're not referencing the primary key. It has to do eager fetch in this case to ensure that there is only one proxy object per ID.

Comment: @JimmyT. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Hibernate has a feature where it modifies the byte code to implement lazy loading without proxys. Theoretically it could solve your problem but I don't know if they also implemented this for non-primary keys